# Profiling CPU cache for C# .net code?

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, cpu-cache

I have seen a couple of tools whereby you can profile the cache for C and C++, but the tool (Valgrind) was intended for Linux and they state on their website it is too much work to develop for windows).

Are there any tools a C# developer can use for profiling the cache?

I have ANTS Performance Profiler but it doesn't perform cache profiling.

Answer (score 0):

Try Intel VTune Amplifier. Using this tool you can collect information about cache hits, misses and some other cache and memory related counters.

I haven't tried it for C# profiling, but it should work the same way as for native C/C++.